# Datatables TableTools with Excel,pdf exporting functions not working with firefox

Tags: jquery, datatables

Datatables TableTools with Excel,pdf exporting functions not working with firefox

I tried the nightly build http://datatables.net/download/build/TableTools.nightly.min.js, different versions and have checked all other posts, nothing seems to get it working in firefox; it works fine in chrome and IE. Please suggest me. Many thanks.

Here's more info: http://debug.datatables.net/ohiwuy and firefox version: 14.0.1

The example on http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/ doesn't work either. The options for copy, pdf, excel appear when loading the page and disappear again. The print option is working.

Comment: I tried with the most stable version, 1.10.8, the Excel export button (HTML5 based) doesn't work either.